# Configuring CakePHP .htaccess in Cpanel ~temp/ URL

Tags: apache, cakephp-2.0

I'm trying to set up CakePHP 2.x in Cpanel (Hostmonster) while the domain of the site is still pointing to the older server. In order to pull up the site without the domain (for demo), I have to use `http://[hosting-IP-address]/~mysite`.

This is my default .htaccess file located in the root (the one before app/ folder):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

If I leave it as it is, I get 404 error. When I remove the .htaccess file or leave it blank, the site content loads, but without CSS. The site files are located in `/home2/mysite/public_html/` folder. I tried adding RewriteBase with different combinations (~mysite, mysite, mysite/public_html), but no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in htaccess file:-

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Hope it will work!

Comment: Yeah, I tried that. What I ended up doing is uncommenting Configure::write('App.baseUrl', env('SCRIPT_NAME')); in the core.php. It looks hideous, but it works (for the demo).

Comment: The .htaccess changes did not solve the problem for me, either the uncommented line in the core.php